# View shared preference file on Android Mobile

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How to view the `shared preference` file from my Android mobile phone , I have tried with `ES-file explorer app` bit confused where to check , Anybody have any idea ?It would be helpful .Note the App is downloaded through `goolge playstore`

Comment: You need to have a rooted phone.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is not debuggable and the phone is not rooted, then you can't access those files.

If your phone is rooted, grant root access to the file manager you are using then go to /data/data/*app name*/shared_prefs/*preference name*.xml

Comment: can i access from unsigned apk?

Comment: not sure about unsigned apk's, but guessing the files will be stored in the same location, it depends if u have root or not